# multiple select for 3 choices per option - or another solution?

Tags: jquery, multiple-select, asmselect

[asmselect](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-asmselect/) is perfect for multiple select boxes with 2 choices (selected, or not).  It does what it should, and well - granted it needs a little styling help.

However, what happens if you need more than one choice for each select option? 
For example, Let's imagine I had a table with two columns of checkboxes:

```
Name     | Displayed | Required

John Doe | Checkbox  | Checkbox (clicking this also checks "displayed")
Jane Doe | Checkbox  | Checkbox (clicking this also checks "displayed")
etc...
```

To display that in another way, for example by using something like asmselect would be counter-intuitive. Are there any decent solutions that do this well already for 2 or more choices per option like this?

Honestly I'm imagining using [multiselec.js](http://loudev.com/), but adding a 3rd box there...  although I wouldn't know where to begin!

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% understand what functionality you're looking for. It sounds like to me that you have one master list of people the user can pick from. When the user picks a person from the list of people they can check or uncheck a box in the `Displayed` and `Required` columns. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @JasonTowne Yessir.  Basically two options true false flags.  Required means it's also displayed.  Displayed only, means it's NOT required.

Comment: Do the selected users need to be sortable? It seems like you could write something simple yourself unless you require additional functionality like sorting, filtering, etc.

Comment: @JasonTowne They do not need to have many special functions.  I'm not yet skilled enough to write my own plugin for this.. maybe in the future... ha.